# How to disable sorting in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutabledictionary

I have a view with `UITableView` and I populate `NSMutableDictionary` and bind it to `UITableView`.
I add items like: `c,b,a,d` but data in table are displayed like: `a,b,c,d`.
Is it possible to disable ordering so items will be displayed in table in the same order as I added them in `NSMutableDictionary`?

Comment: NSMutableDictoinaries dont store order at all, you would need to use an array if you want to keep the order

Comment: While they don't store order, in my experience if you request the objects, they tend to return them with the keys in alphabetical ordering...but you can't guarantee this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order objects are displayed in your table view matters, you should be using an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`.  These are the only Objective-C collections for which the order can be guaranteed, and they work a lot easier with table views than any other collections, given that their objects are stored at indexes and these can match exactly to the row portion of the `NSIndexPath` argument of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.